Make rigidbody follow another object in Unity
I am working on pirate roguelike game, I am using CREST Ocean system for a ocean and boats.
Here’s how my boat work: there is object called BoatSystem that controlls movement of a boat (it has a rigidbody and some other CREST components) and it’s basically just a long capsule. Then I have a model of my boat that uses script to follow my BoatSystem. Here is the script for it:
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowObjectWithOffset : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform targetObject;
public Vector3 offset;        

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (targetObject != null)
    {
        transform.position = targetObject.position + offset;
        transform.rotation = targetObject.rotation;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Target Object not found!");
    }
}

}
When I used custom character controller with rigidbody, I just made my player a child object for a boat model and it worked fine, but I didn’t like it, so I started using Kinematic Character Controller (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/physics/kinematic-character-controller-99131?srsltid=AfmBOorzdAILzbv2L-r2-oHW3wFo2xFWL-MNlgst9FZpcY7EpD5uZ3EM)
And now it doesn’t work at all. When my boat moves, my character just stays on the same place. How do I make him move with the boat?

well you arent moving using physics, but, as long as the items are set it should move..  so, it implies either the target object is not moving, but some subpart of it does.. which sounds weird, but, with the info provided the only conclusion can be your target isnt moving
